# print in firefox makes fonts bigger

Tags: css, firefox, printing

I used a css file for print, everything is good in IE and Chrome but in FireFox font's are much bigger!!!! i don't know what's wrong with firefox.
Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

here is my css file

```
*,:before,:after {
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body 
{
    width: auto; 
    height: auto;
     float: none !important;
    margin:10px 20px;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family:  "B Yagut", "B Titr";
     line-height: 220%;
    font-size:18pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    direction:rtl;
}

#header,
#footer,
#nav,
#section,
legend,
#bottom-controls, 
#bottom-details,
#tabs-2, 
#tabs-3 {
    display: none;
}

#main {
    width: auto; 
     float: none !important;
    padding: 0;
    height:auto;
}
p { line-height:220%;  font-size:18pt;  font-weight:bold;}
strong { line-height:220%;}




#tabs, fieldset, #tabs-1 {  width: auto;  border-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;  line-height:200%;   font-size:18pt;
    font-weight:bold;}
#tabs ul, #cssmenu{
    display: none;
}
```

thanks everybody.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/966081, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/788774, https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=firefox+print+large&oq=firefox+print+large&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2756j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: none of them helped me.